# How to display only a few pagination custom bulletRender

Tags: javascript, html

When the swiper bullets gets too much it overflows. I want to only cache a few slides in the DOM but still keep the nice custom names for each bullet swiper.

This is for a timeline swiper on a website.

https://codepen.io/Barnicles/pen/OYbdQq

```
var timelineSwiper = new Swiper ('.timeline .swiper-container', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  loop: false,
  speed: 1600,
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationBulletRender: function (swiper, index, className) {
    var year = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide')[index].getAttribute('data-year');
    return '<span class="' + className + '">' + year + '</span>';
  },
  paginationClickable: true,
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  breakpoints: {
    768: {
      direction: 'horizontal',
    }
  }

});
```

I expect the paginationBulletRender to keep including span classes and fill the whole screen but I only want to have a few on the screen.

Comment: http://idangero.us/swiper/api/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line: `pagination: '.swiper-pagination'`,

Try this:

```
pagination: {
           el: ".swiper-pagination",
           dynamicBullets: true,
           dynamicMainBullets: 3
   }
```